# C++ keeps skipping my "for" loop

Tags: c++, function, for-loop

I'm trying to create a program that will find a four-digit number that meets four specific requirements: all four digits are different, the thousands number is 3x the tens number, the number is odd, and the sum of the digits is 27. For some reason, despite the program compiling, the for loop won't run and always outputs the initializer number (1000). My main code and the four functions I'm calling are below. I can't figure out why it won't run correctly. I'm completely new to coding so any tips/help are appreciated. Thanks!

main function:

```
      5 //prototypes
      6 bool differentDigits(int);
      7 bool thouThreeTen(int);
      8 bool numberIsOdd(int);
      9 bool sumIs27(int);
     10 
     11 #include <iostream>
     12 using namespace std;
     13 
     14 int main ()
     15 {
     16         //variables
     17         int n;
     18 
     19         //processing
     20 
     21         for(n=1000;n<=9999;n++)
     22         {
     23                 if(differentDigits(n)==true)
     24                 {
     25                         break;
     26                 }
     27 
     28                 if(thouThreeTen(n)==true)
     29                 {
     30                         break;
     31                 }
     32 
     33                 if(numberIsOdd(n)==true)
     34                 {
     35                         break;
     36                 }
     37 
     38                 if(sumIs27(n)==true)
     39                 {
     40                         break;
     41                 }
     42 
     43         }
     44 
     45         //output
     46         cout << n << endl;
     47 
     48         return 0;
     49 }
```

differentDigits function:

```
      3 //Verify all four digits are the same
      4 
      5 #include <iostream>
      6 using namespace std;
      7 
      8 bool differentDigits (int n)
      9 {
      10         int n1, n2, n3, n4;
      11 
      12         n1 = n/1000;
      13         n2 = (n/100) % 10;
      14         n3 = (n/10) % 10;
      15         n4 = n % 10;
      16 
      17         if(n1 != n2 != n3 != n4)
      18         {
      19                 return true;
      20         }
      21         else
      22         {
      23                 return false;
      24         }
      25 
      26 }
```

thouThreeTen function:

```
      3 //Verify digit in thousands place is 3x the digit in tens place
      4 
      5 #include <iostream>
      6 using namespace std;
      7 
      8 bool thouThreeTen(int n)
      9 {
      10         int n1, n2, n3, n4;
      11 
      12         n1 = n/1000;
      13         n2 = (n/100) % 10;
      14         n3 = (n/10) % 10;
      15         n4 = n % 10;
      16 
      17         if(n1 = (n3 * 3))
      18         {
      19                 return true;
      20         }
      21         else
      22         {
      23                 return false;
      24         }
      25 
      26 }
```

numberIsOdd function:

```
      3 //Verify that the number is odd
      4 
      5 #include <iostream>
      6 using namespace std;
      7 
      8 bool numberIsOdd (int n)
      9 {
      10         if((n % 2)==1)
      11         {
      12                 return true;
      13         }
      14         else
      15         {
      16                 return false;
      17         }
      18 
      19 }
```

sumIs27 function:

```
      3 //Verify that the sum of digits is 27
      4 
      5 #include <iostream>
      6 using namespace std;
      7 
      8 bool sumIs27(int n)
      9 {
      10         int n1, n2, n3, n4;
      11 
      12         n1 = n/1000;
      13         n2 = (n/100) % 10;
      14         n3 = (n/10) % 10;
      15         n4 = n % 10;
      16 
      17         if((n1+n2+n3+n4)==27)
      18         {
      19                 return true;
      20         }
      21         else
      22         {
      23                 return false;
      24         }
      25 
      26 }
```

Comment: `if(n1 != n2 != n3 != n4)` doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: Why would this question be upvoted???

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. 
With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. 
This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `if(n1 = (n3 * 3))` needs to be `if(n1 == (n3 * 3))`

Comment: Your `for` loop isn't being skipped. One of your conditionals evidently succeeds (returns `true`) with `n` equal to 1000, so you break out of the loop at that time.

Comment: your texts says you want to leave the loop if all conditions are met, but your code says to break if any of them is met

Comment: You are either ignoring warning or not running your compiler with maximum level of warning. Both are wrong choices.

Comment: Fundamentally, you are missing a vital rule: when you write code, start with something small and simple that works perfectly, then add complexity a little at a time, testing at every step.

Comment: Please don't add line numbers like that - it makes it hard to copy and reproduce your issue.  If you need to draw attention to particular lines, use a comment to mark the line of interest - better still, reduce your example so that it is *minimal*, so that it's obvious where the error lies.

Comment: Better write `if (differentDigits(n) )` insteed of `if ( differentDigits(n)==true )` .

Comment: @MikeVine what does it do?

Comment: @eh3 Relational (binary) operators are evaluated left-to-right, so `if(((n1 != n2) != n3) != n4)`, which is unlikely what you want.

Comment: @MikeVine ah ok, I changed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems with your code, the first being in `main()`. If any of the functions return true, you will end the loop. This is probably why you see the `for` loop as not being executed. Another problem is that in your functions, you are using conditions such as `if(n1 = (n3 * 3))` which use the assignment operator instead of checking if they are the same.You want to use `if(n1 == (n3 * 3))`. Your main should look something like:

```
int main()
{
    int n = 0;

    for(n = 1000; n < 9999; ++n)
    {
        if(differentDigits(n) && thouThreeTen(n) && numberIsOdd(n) && sumIs27(n))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << n << endl;
}
```

In each of your functions, make sure that you are using `==` not `=` when you are checking if something is a value.

Comment: Thanks so much!! Worked perfectly. I forgot about using "==" instead of "=".